# how to take input from options ,while i have to input data into two tables of a same database,based on option data will be inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in a database where i have to input data through a form, but the condition is-there is a select option in the form and as the option we have to insert data .
if option 1 is chosen then the data should be inserted to  table x
and if option 2 is chosen then the data should be inserted to table y

I have tried using switch case and elseif
but couldn'
  t find the right condition for it.
    html code-

```
        <form method="post" class="register-form" id="register-form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="name"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="aname" id="name" placeholder="Your Name"/>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i></label>
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email"/>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="address"><i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Your Address"/>
                                    </div>
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="user"><i class="zmdi zmdi-accounts-alt"></i></label>
                                        <select  id="person-type" name="logtype" required style="border-top: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);border-right: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);border-left: rgba(0,0,0,0.0); width: 100%;margin-left: 22px;">
                                            <option disabled selected  value="">Select your login type</option>
                                            <option value="consumer" name="consumer">Consumer</option>
                                            <option value="electrician" name="electrician">Electrician</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></label>
                                        <input type="password" name="apass" id="password" pattern=".{6,}" required placeholder="Password "  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Password must be 6 digit long or more')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"  />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="re-pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock-outline"></i></label>
                                        <input type="password" name="re_pass" id="confirm_password"required="@" minlength="8" placeholder="Repeat your password"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="agree-term" id="agree-term" class="agree-term"  required/>
                                        <label for="agree-term" class="label-agree-term"><span><span></span></span>I agree all statements in  <a href="#" class="term-service">Terms of service</a></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group form-button">
                                        <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" class="form-submit" value="Register"/>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

php code-

```php
if (isset($_POST['signup'])) 
{
    if ($_POST['logtype'] == 'consumer') 
    {
        $consumer=mysqli_query($edb,"insert into consumer(name,email,address,logtype,password) values('".$_POST['aname']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['address']."','".$_POST['logtype']."',md5.
                            ('".$_POST['apass']."'))");    
                                header("Location:loginonly.php");
                }
                elseif ( $_POST['logtype'] == 'electrician' ) 
                {

                            $electrician=mysqli_query($edb,"insert into electrician(name,email,address,logtype,password) values('".$_POST['aname']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['address']."','".$_POST['logtype']."',md5.
                                ('".$_POST['apass']."'))");    
                                header("Location:loginonly.php");
                }
```

no errors, while the data is not inserted in tables

Comment: Have you tested the sql query in your sql console?

Comment: Don't use md5 for password hashing!. Use password_hash() to create a secure hash and password_verify() to verify a password against a hash

Comment: yes. normally its uploading with the querry, but when i put the condition it doesn't  insert data

Comment: You're using the PHP md5 function wrong. In the console you're don't use md5 because your string is already a md5 string. And that's the error.

Comment: Whats the output of `$_POST['logtype']`?

Comment: Show us your html form code

Comment: thats not the error  if i send data normally to database  without the condition for select option , data is inserting smoothly with no such errors.

Comment: @imoverflow see i have uploaded all the codes now. please help me out here

Comment: In your php code, i think you are not closing if (isset($_POST['signup']))  statement properly

Comment: thank you guys i have solved the problem

Comment: what was the problem ?

Comment: instead of if ($_POST['logtype'] == 'consumer') i used  if ($_REQUEST['logtype'] == "consumer")  and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You should add some error handling to your query execution to help find what's happening.

Basic mysqli error handing in php would be something like:

```
<?php
 if (!mysqli_query($edb,"YOUR QUERY HERE"))
 {
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_POST['logtype'] == 'consumer') {
             $consumer=mysqli_query($edb,"insert into consumer(name,email,address,logtype,password) values('".$_POST['aname']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['address']."','".$_POST['logtype']."',md5('".$_POST['apass']."'))");                            header("Location:loginonly.php");
        }
        elseif ( $_POST['logtype'] == 'electrician' ) 
        {
           $electrician=mysqli_query($edb,"insert into electrician(name,email,address,logtype,password) values('".$_POST['aname']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['address']."','".$_POST['logtype']."',md5('".$_POST['apass']."'))");    
header("Location:loginonly.php");
        }
```

May be you are using md5 method wrong

Comment: nothing wrong with md5 or hashing working properly but the condition for  comparing the selected value from option is not working

Comment: are you passing these values statically? Means from dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the md5 function wrong.

```
'" . md5($_POST['apass']) . "'
```

instead of

`md5.('".$_POST['apass']."')` //md5 has to be in the PHP part in double quotes

To minimize the error sources i would prefer this code:

```
if ($_POST['logtype'] === 'consumer') {
    $table = "consumer";
}elseif ( $_POST['logtype'] === 'electrician' ){
    $table = "electrician";
}

$apass = md5($_POST['apass']);

$consumer = mysqli_query($edb,"insert into " . $table . " (name,email,address,logtype,password) values('".$_POST['aname']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['address']."','".$_POST['logtype']."','" . $apass . "'))");
header("Location:loginonly.php");
```

Comment: nothing wrong with hashing or normally sending data to the table, it is not working only  when m using the condition for options

Answer (score 0):

There was syntax error in your query near md5 function. Its getting executed as md5.(password) instead of md5(password).
Also its advisable to keep error logging on php in development mode. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: md5 was working perfectly , had an issue with the condition where we have to compare with the option for data input.